# Escribir Fichero DataOutputStream Java

Tags: java

quería escribir en un fichero llamado datos.dat e hice el siguiente código para ello:

```
package ejercicio_1_2;

import java.io.*;

public class Ejercicio_1_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fichero = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\archivos_creados\\datos.dat");
        DataOutputStream dataoutput = new DataOutputStream(fichero);
        int var_entero = 65; // Obtenemos el valor de A porque es 65 en codigo ASCII
        float var_flotante = 2.8f;
        double var_double = 4.56;
        dataoutput.writeInt(var_entero);
        dataoutput.writeFloat(var_flotante);
        dataoutput.writeDouble(var_double);
        dataoutput.close();
    }
}
```

El problema viene en la forma en que se escriben los datos al fichero, en código ASCII. Hay alguna forma para que no se escriba en ASCII y se escriba tal cual: 65, 2.8f, 4.56? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se deben convertir a su equivalente en cadena.

```
 dataoutput.writeBytes(String.valueOf(var_entero));
 dataoutput.writeBytes(String.valueOf(var_flotante));
 dataoutput.writeBytes(String.valueOf(var_double));
```

`65` como valor interno en memoria  es el equivalente al caracter `A`. Pero en un archivo de texto `65` son dos caracteres: `'6' = 54 y '5' = 53.`

Los métodos como `writeInt()` escriben bytes al archivo y en tu caso lo que quieres ver son caracteres.